# when i run ng serve i get the bellow error. i tried to add ("css-loader": "^2.1.0") in the dependencies but dint work

Tags: angular-cli

Error: ./src/styles.css
Module build failed (from ./node_modules/mini-css-extract-plugin/dist/loader.js):
ModuleBuildError: Module build failed (from ./node_modules/postcss-loader/dist/cjs.js):
Error: EISDIR: illegal operation on a directory, read
at C:\Users\Admin\Desktop\res\restaurant\node_modules\webpack\lib\NormalModule.js:316:20
at C:\Users\Admin\Desktop\res\restaurant\node_modules\loader-runner\lib\LoaderRunner.js:367:11
at C:\Users\Admin\Desktop\res\restaurant\node_modules\loader-runner\lib\LoaderRunner.js:233:18
at context.callback (C:\Users\Admin\Desktop\res\restaurant\node_modules\loader-runner\lib\LoaderRunner.js:111:13)
at Object.loader (C:\Users\Admin\Desktop\res\restaurant\node_modules\postcss-loader\dist\index.js:56:7)

Error: ./src/app/app.component.css
Module build failed (from ./node_modules/postcss-loader/dist/cjs.js):
Error: EISDIR: illegal operation on a directory, read

Comment: have you imported css path in your `style` block under 'angular.json` file if yes then check that path properly because that wrong path create problem some time

Comment: Please provide more than just an error. Even though this is a coding stack exchange, we need reproducibility. Also, make the title short and summative and without grammatical errors. Please correct it quickly or people may downvote your question.